# Query Selector questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Can you take something like...

```
var skullclick = document.querySelector('input[value="Small Haunted Skull"]').click();
```

and then make it so that it will find more like..

```
var skullclick = document.querySelector('input[value="* Small Haunted Skull"]').click();
```

the * referring to anything before this is accepted , the way its shown on the page is # Small Haunted Skulls so i can't just do Small Haunted Skulls, Or am I wrong?
a.k.a the problem I'm having is I'm just unsure if you are actually able to take just a part of the text rather then the requirement of the entire text given and it still come out the same way as if you were to add the numbers before hand.

Comment: Hmm, what is the aim of your code? What do you want it to do?

Comment: This is the pages code for the button
http://puu.sh/ln4JD/cbe65f9956.png
i'm simply trying to make TamperMonkey click that specific thing, the problem is i can't go by the id since the slot is always changing where that item is. so i want it to find the "Small Haunted Skulls" part of the innerhtml and click that button rather then something else.

Comment: Stefan's should work for you then

Comment: It doesn't look at my comment on his.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out what you are asking. You want something automatically clicked? If you are just trying to find an element that contains particular text, use jquery and check out `selector:contains`

Comment: It should be with the way it's written is to click Automatically the "Small Haunted Skulls" find, and then the Use buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

`input[attribute$="Small Haunted Skull"]` might just be what you are looking for.

Comment: http://puu.sh/ln6C5/e6a2279f41.png
Doesn't seem to be working it's as if nothing is actually going on really, the stamina is coming back 0 (should be) so by that if statement it should click the small haunted skulls button then click the use after that.

without clicking it 
http://puu.sh/ln6GN/9a5fb2907b.png

After clicking (how it should look)
http://puu.sh/ln6Jy/5cc19c5471.png

Comment: Check your console. It looks to me like you are having a typo in in your setIntervall call (";" too much).